# Want to integrate aws ELB dns_name with api gateway endpoint via terraform

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws, aws-elb

Am able to launch a elb via terraform and in output file stored the dns name of that ELB. Now I want to integrate that url with my api gateway via terraform, but unable to do that.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "demo" {
  name = "${var.api_name}"

  invoke_url = "${var.invoke_url}" 

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["${var.api_type}"]
  }
}
```

**invoke_url = "${module.elb.elb_dns_name}**

api-gateway url should be like - http://xxx.aws.elb.com/api

Comment: What have you tried? Did you get an error? Did something not work? Can you edit your question to include a [mcve] and the full error output if you get anything?

Answer (score 0):

As you've probably gathered `invoke_url` is not a valid argument on the rest API.

I would recommend following [this article](https://medium.com/@maciejtreder/custom-domain-in-aws-api-gateway-a2b7feaf9c74) to see how custom domain names can be attached to API Gateway instances via the AWS console.

Once you've understand that, you should be able to reverse-engineer the necessary terraform using resources like [api_gateway_domain_name](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_domain_name.html).